# Different views of TabHost

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-tabhost

App is currently in the store "CalculateMe" It appears differently in different devices. The first one is Galaxy S3 and the second one is Galaxy S1. Not sure how I can fix this so it appears similarly to the first one.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is maybe because of the theme your are using in your activity.

e.g. If you are using the default theme of device in your manifest.
Samsung Galaxy S3 has 4.2 version of android which has the Holo Theme (picture 1).
While Galaxy S1 has 2.3 which only has the default android Theme without the visual effects of Holo (picture 2). I believe this is the problem in your case.

**Possible Solutions:**

1)Either define your own theme to style the tabhost and set it in your activity.

2)Or you can use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) or [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) in your project. Probably it will require more time, but it will solve many problems with theming on Holo and pre-Holo devices.